# AdHoc build install fails via both testflight & iTunes

Tags: iphone, rubymotion, testflight, ad-hoc-distribution

I am getting this error - http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829652

I tried this (but did not fix the problem) -  http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/867631

I tried installing the adhoc build via iTunes (still no luck) - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OF7bstiw_9o

I am using the AdHoc provisioning profile(with my phone listed in it) and distribution certificate. I also went ahead and deleted/created a new adhoc distribution profile, just to see if that fixes the problem.

Also if it counts, I am building for iOS 7.0. I can see the adhoc provisioning profile installed on my iphone via the iPhone Configuration Utility.

Anyone know where I could be going wrong?

Comment: in testflight you can check the permission-tab of your app and see if your device-id is listed

Comment: @Thorsten yea I see my name in the "Teammates In The Provisioning Profile" list for the app

Answer (score 0):

One of the potential causes listed in the link you posted is 'Architecture settings of the build and the device are incompatible ( can sometimes happen when "Build Active Architecture Only" is on when building).'

One possible reason for this is that you had the device connected to the computer when you did the build. The build may have been optimised for the architecture of the attached device and the device you are trying to install to may have a different architecture